# What is the reference counting in Lua?

Tags: lua, garbage-collection, reference-counting

See the following example:

```
local t = {}

t[1] = function() return 3 end 
t[2] = function() return 2 end
t[3] = 3

local a = t[1]

local b = t
t[1] = nil
collectgarbage("collect") --reclaim memory
print(a)  --function
print(b[1])   -- nil
print(b[2])   --function
print(b[3])   --3
```

Why can I still print the 'a' instead of 'b[1]'?
In addition, I see "A weak reference is ignored by the garbage collector" in the lua reference manual. How to define "ignore"?

Answer (score 3):

Assignment (`=`) assigns the value of something in Lua, it never creates an alias.

Thus it's simply irrelevant to `a` that you assign `nil` to `b[1]`, after you assigned `b[1]` to `a`.

---

Regarding your GC question:

You only have strong references in your snippet, no weak ones.
And *ignored* means not followed when determining life objects. Of course it is `nil`-ed out if the target is declared unreachable.
Lua has a tracing GC, not a reference-counting one, which would have problems with circular references.

Comment: Where could I find the materials about lua GC?

Comment: Look up the official documentation on the Lua website.It's quite readable. http://www.lua.org/manual/